# How to Call/access control combobox asp devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, combobox, devexpress

I want to call my combobox in my gridview to function `btnShow_Click`, but when i type ID of combobox in C# the names object is doesnt exist in current context.

For informatition my gridview have 3 datasource
and my combobox i want to set 3 datasource (1 gridview there is 3 conditional datasource AND have 3 conditional combobox datasource)

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ddl = ddlApp.Value.ToString();
        if (ddl == "ATTD")
        {
            GvMenu.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSourceAttd";
            GvMenu.DataBind();
        }
        else if (ddl == "TRVL")
        {
            GvMenu.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSourceTrvl";
            GvMenu.DataBind();
        }
        else if (ddl == "CORE")
        {
            GvMenu.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSourceCore";
            GvMenu.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

*In aspx gridview*

[![pieces of code my gridview][1]][1]

```
<dx:GridviewDataComboboxcolumn  FieldName="ParentMenuID" visibleindex="2" Caption="Parent Menu ID" showincustomizationform="true" >

            <PropertiesComboBox ValueField="ParentMenuID" TextField="ParentMenuID" ValueType="System.String" >
            </PropertiesComboBox>

        </dx:GridviewDataComboboxcolumn>
```

Comment: It is better to insert the code as the text rather than as the image. The reason is that one cannot simply copy the code in the image and edit it in the Answer. It is necessary to retype the code from the image if one want to illustrate required corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are using only the ASPxComboBox and the ASPxLabel components in cell templates. You can achieve the same result using the [GridViewDataComboBoxColumn](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebGridViewDataComboBoxColumntopic).

```
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ParentMenuID">
  <PropertiesComboBox ValueType="System.String" />
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

if (ddl == "ATTD")
{
  var parentMenuColumn = (GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)GvMenu.Columns["ParentMenuID"];
  parentMenuColumn.PropertiesComboBox.DataSourceID = "Your Data Source ID";
  GvMenu.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSourceAttd";
  GvMenu.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: still error in "PropertiesComboBox"

"does not contain a definition for "PropertiesComboBox" and no extentsion method .....

Comment: I forgot the important detail - GvMenu.Columns [index] returns an instance of the base class. So, upcast is necessary. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ASPxGridView.FindRowCellTemplateControl method to find a control residing in the column's DataItemTemplate container. Please also refer to the [Accessing Controls Contained within Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3922) topic.

> Best place to customize controls is the Init and Load event and these
>   events should be used for the controls initialization: Init and Load.
>   [The general technique of using the Init/Load event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18282)

Refer these:
[Find controls in the DataItem template of ASPxGridView column](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/find-controls-in-dataitemtemplate-of.html)
[How to Find DataItemTemplate control inside OnCustomButtonCallback event using c# in server side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T210665)
[ASPxGridView - How to find a control inside the DataItem template](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q339842)

**For changing datasource of the grid at run time:**
[ASPxGridView - How to change datasources for the grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q319878)
[ASPxGridView - How to change Datasource at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q580110)
[ASPxGridView - How to change a datasource dynamically](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q298936)
[How to dynamically switch the grid's data source and recreate columns at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E448)

> Please examine the [How to dynamically switch the grid's data source
>   and recreate columns at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E448.aspx) example from our Code Central,
>   which demonstrates how to switch datasources at runtime. I recommend
>   that you review other examples mentioned in this sample.

Comment: then use the Init event of the combo boxes and that will be the right place to do as per your requirement

Comment: Can you give me other example?
im newbie for devexpress

thx a lot

Comment: it's so simple. change your aspx edittemplate @AzharSetiawan

Comment: sorry sir im still dont understand how to applied the example of code to my project. 
when i create init and htmlrowcreated my  code is still wrong.

can you give me the example of code to call combobox, and set datasource with sqldatasource.

Or can you give me step by step what must I do if you see a pieces of my code above

thx a lot

Comment: Please check the added example and devexpress thread for finding correct way to change data source at run time